# Validate id sequence consistency in records in Redshift

Tags: redshift, gaps-and-islands

I have a backend that log event to Redshift, for each event it generates a unique id. The id is a sequential number.

I have something like (`events` table):

```
+-------------------------+------+
| created_at              |  id  |
+-------------------------+------+
| 2017-06-30 09:20:47 UTC | 100  |
| 2017-06-30 09:18:31 UTC | 101  |
| 2017-06-30 09:16:19 UTC | 102  |
| 2017-06-30 09:12:08 UTC | 103  |
| 2017-06-30 09:11:59 UTC | 104  |
| 2017-06-30 09:11:15 UTC | 105  |
| 2017-06-30 07:03:41 UTC | 106  |
+-------------------------+------+
```

I have task than run every hour that move few records to an other table (`deactivated_events`).

I would like to verify that for the last 3 hours I don't have any missing record using `id` sequence. 
First I thought about using generate_series but this is not present in Redshift. Other suggested to make a table with only the ids but that's still a pain to populate database with integer ([here one example to generate 1 million](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35500173/2747638)

I'm wondering if the best is not use min max and count like this :

```
WITH merged_events AS
  (SELECT *
   FROM
     (SELECT id, created_at
      FROM events
      UNION 
      SELECT id, created_at
      FROM deactivated_events
     )
   WHERE created_at > GETDATE() - INTERVAL '3 hours'
   ORDER BY id)
SELECT COUNT(*), (max(id) - min(id) + 1) AS diff
FROM merged_events;
```

PS: Bonus, how to found missing or duplicate records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's imagine you have this setup:

```
INSERT INTO events
    (created_at, id)
VALUES
    ('2017-06-30 09:20:47 UTC', 100),
    -- ('2017-06-30 09:18:31 UTC', 101), -- Missing row
    ('2017-06-30 09:16:19 UTC', 102),
    ('2017-06-30 09:12:08 UTC', 103),
    ('2017-06-30 09:11:59 UTC', 104),
    ('2017-06-30 09:11:15 UTC', 105),
    ('2017-06-30 07:03:41 UTC', 106) ;
```

and ...

```
INSERT INTO deactivated_events
    (created_at, id)
VALUES
    ('2017-06-30 07:03:41 UTC', 97),
    ('2017-06-30 09:11:15 UTC', 98),
    ('2017-06-30 09:11:15 UTC', 99),
    ('2017-06-30 09:18:31 UTC', 100)     -- Repeated row
    ;
```

Provided that Redshift provides [`Window Functions`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html), you can use a slight variation of your query to do two things:

1. Consider that there are repeated `id`s when you group by `id` and find the count to be > 1
2. Consider that there is a missing row (or more!) if the `id` of the previous row is not 1 + the current one. This is done by means of the [`LAG` function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LAG.html).

This can be done with the following query

```
WITH merged_events AS
(
  SELECT 
      id
  FROM
  (
      SELECT 
          id
      FROM 
          events
      UNION ALL  /* Must be UNION ALL, because we want to find repeated values */
      SELECT 
          id
      FROM 
          deactivated_events
  ) AS q0
  WHERE true -- In practice, created_at > GETDATE() - INTERVAL '3 hours'
)
SELECT 
    id, 
    count(id) > 1 AS repeated_event, 
    ((lag(id) OVER(ORDER BY id)) /* previous id */ + 1) <> id AS previous_event_missing
FROM 
    merged_events
GROUP BY
    id ;
```

This will produce:

```
 id | repeated_event | previous_event_missing
--: | :------------- | :---------------------
 97 | f              | null                  
 98 | f              | f                     
 99 | f              | f                     
100 | TRUE           | f                     
102 | f              | TRUE                     
103 | f              | f                     
104 | f              | f                     
105 | f              | f                     
106 | f              | f
```

You can check the whole setup (with PostgreSQL instead of RedShift) at 
*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=50ee6e8ae2d23e4f388b244a506026b9)*

---

**Caveats**: your `id` might have gaps if it is actually from an `IDENTITY` column (or a `SEQUENCE` it Redshift happens to implement it, which I don't think is the case). So, you should first guarantee by some other means that your ids are originally consecutive...

References:

- [Sequence number generation function in AWS redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643338/sequence-number-generation-function-in-aws-redshift) which discusses different ways of getting sequences, and its tradeoffs.
- [How to find missing values in a sequence with SQL](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/12/06/find-missing-numbers-in-a-sequence-with-sql/) which shows different alternatives.

Comment: That's a very good idea to use `lag`. Didn't think about it. Thanks for additional links

Comment: If I want to return only rows that have an issue `IS TRUE` do I need to make a new CTE that gets all the queries and add a WHERE clause to it?

Comment: That's one possibility. Another one is to convert the whole existing query into a subquery (`SELECT * FROM (WITH ....) AS q0 WHERE q0.repeated_event or q0.previous_event_missing`)

Answer (score 1):

> I have task than run every hour that move few records to an other table (deactivated_events).

This sounds like a really bad idea. Instead, I would urge you to create a new column `active` of type `bool`. Especially if you're needing to merge events from that table.

> PS: Bonus, how to found missing or duplicate records?

That will stop being a problem if you stop deleting from the table.

Also, see @joanolo's notes on sequences. That's also true of [`IDENTITY COLUMNS` on Redshift,](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html)

> To be sure that the identity values are unique, Amazon Redshift skips a number of values when creating the identity values. As a result, identity values are sequential, but not consecutive.

Generally, you don't want to move data out of a table to archive it. Especially if you don't have to. PostgreSQL 10 is coming out. Redshift may very well upgrade to using it. If they do, you'll have [value partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-partitioning.html) which will do this transparently and automatically.

Comment: Thanks @evan-carroll. My missing records are happening because of random errors in Firehose (1 error every month) not because of moving rows to an other table. Sorry if I was not clear. Do you think Redshift will update? Thanks for the link